# Implement x=T if abs(x)>T as an activation function in pytorch

Tags: python, pytorch, activation-function

I would like to implement the following activation function in pytorch:

```
x = T if abs(x)>T else x
```

I could do something close with torch.clamp(min=-T, max=T) but it's not exactly the behavior I want (this would behave the same as above for x>-T but would return -T for x<-T). Is there any torch function that could help me achieve this?

Comment: There's a discontinuity at x = -T, that seems to me like an issue for optimization reasons (for one thing the function has no derivative or sub-derivative at x=-T).

Comment: I know but this was suggested by some paper: we don't actually care about the truncated values so whether they are -T or T does not change much. Setting them both to the same value allows to reduce the variance of the feature map (c.f. https://arxiv.org/pdf/1912.06540.pdf)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`torch.where`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torch.html#torch.where) does exactly that:

[image: torch.where]

```py
x = torch.where(torch.abs(x) > T, T, x)
```